# Add Ant target to Liferay Developer SDK context menu

Tags: ant, liferay

When I add an extra ant target to one of the default Ant build files in Liferay Developer Studio I can choose this target from the context menu of the project build.xml file in the Ant window. But I would like to be able to choose this extra target from the context menu when I right click the project and then Liferay -> SDK. I have tried to add the extra target to several files but it's never shown in the list with Ant targets.
How can I add extra targets to this menu?